# Body in html is above the navbar

Tags: html, css

I have this problem when i want to put some text in my body or place something like a div or a section there , the text goes above the navbar which is in header.I tried to put a margin top to the body but it only made a bigger gap between the top.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
body{
  background-color: #444064;
  margin-top:10ex;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0,auto;
  padding: 0,auto;
  list-style: none;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2ex;
  padding: 5ex;
}
nav a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 4ex;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: #a34963;
}
section{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5ex;
}
h1{
  font-size: xx-large;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="wrapper">
   <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">     
    </head>
    <header>
            <div id="menu">
                <img src="Logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
            <home>                  
                <nav class="menu">                          
                    <ol>                   
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </nav>
            </home>
           </div>
   </header> 
    <body>
        Hello world
    </body>
</div>  
</html>
```

Please help me

Comment: You have an absolutely incorrect html structure. Read this please - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Document_and_website_structure

Comment: invalid HTML you have here. `<head>` should be right on the top `between the `<html>` tag. After the closing of the `</head>` element the `<body>` should come. Everything elese should go betwwen the body tags.

Comment: it's happen because of .logo{float:left;} css and also you need to correct the html structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many issues with your code as you have an invalid HTML structure. however the issue you have is: `nav { float: right; }` that causes you navbar to float and as such the content can flow around the nav element and be displayed above. If you remove the line it not happen anymore.

However, I strongly recommend to get back to some decent tutorials and start at the basics. Like I said your HTML structure is an invalid mess. Some css declarations are incorrect/unnecessary as well (e.g. webkit prefix for box-sizing). Also don't use float as styling technique. Use a modern solution like flexbox or css-grid.

Last but not least, this is how the html structure should look like.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: #444064;
  margin-top: 10ex;
}

nav {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2ex;
  padding: 5ex;
}

nav a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 4ex;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #a34963;
}

section {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5ex;
}

h1 {
  font-size: xx-large;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div id="menu">
      <img src="Logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
      <home>
        <nav class="menu">
          <ol>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ol>
        </nav>
      </home>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div id="wrapper">
    Hello world
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```